# How to navigate to specific screen on backhandler in reat native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I want to navigate to my home screen from my login screen when i tap the back handler button on mobile  but it is exiting me from the app. Please tell me how can i navigate to any particular screen .thanks

My code:

```
    backAction = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Mainhome');
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      this.backAction,
    );
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.backAction);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
backAction = async () => {
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Mainhome');
};
```

Comment: Thank u so muchhhh